# Cant Run MAUI Project getting below Error - The Project need to be deployed before we can debug. please enable deploy in the Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

[image]When i try to run new MAUI Project below Error is popping up. can someone help me out to solve this issue . i tick the deploy and build in the configuration manager also

Error Message - The Project need to be deployed before we can debug. please enable deploy in the Configuration Manager

I have tick the Deploy option in the Configuration manager still get the issue

Comment: Make sure that you are able to deploy for the target architecture (e.g. that you have configured an android emulator or that you have an android phone connected with developer options and USB debugging enabled if you try to debug the android target)

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: @Jason  I m try to run as windows machine

Comment: please [edit] your question and transcribe any error messages as text

Comment: @Jason .The Project need to be deployed before we can debug. please enable deploy in the Configuration Manager

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Not sure why, I've gotten other .NET MAUI apps to work before, but it won't run new ones.

Comment: I had to start the project from its raw path on the hard drive rather than a mapped network drive in order to get past this error.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error when I used a space in my solution and project:
'my solution'. I deleted the solution and created a new one with a name without spaces: 'mysolution' and it worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was renamed this tag.

```
<!-- App Identifier -->
<ApplicationId>com.companyname.my_app_name</ApplicationId>
```

To

```
<!-- App Identifier -->
<ApplicationId>com.companyname.myappname</ApplicationId>
```

Without underscore.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked and solved the seam issue I have encountered today.

Comment: Don't forget to vote. :p

Answer (score 1):

Please try to right click your solution -> `Configuration Manager`,

then pop up the Configuration Manager dialog, please enable the `Deploy` option.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I tick the deploy option in the configuration manager still i  get the issue

Comment: You can try to delete the obj and bin folders and rebuild it.

Comment: I have this problem with .NET8. "Deploy" was already checked, closing VS and deleting bin/obj yields two new errors: NETSDK1005 and XA1018 -- and I haven't changed the Windows or Android build targets. The number of bugs in MAUI is staggering.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally realized that there should not be any underline character in the project title.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when my App Identifier was greater than 50 characters.

I changed it in my app's csproj

```
<!-- App Identifier -->
<ApplicationId>THIS MUST BE LESS THAN 50 CHARS</ApplicationId>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, turning on Developer Mode in Windows Setting & restarting Visual Studio worked for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 11 Home, this worked for me:

Enable developer mode.
Backup project files.
Close and delete the existing project.
Create a new project.
Restore backup.

Answer (score 0):

Close your vs and delete the hidden folder ".vs" at the root of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Was facing this issue when trying to build from local, changing this option helped me

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the HardDrive Filesystem the project was stored on. It has to be NTFS, extFat does not work for certain .Net Projects incl. .Net Maui.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem in
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.2

I found the remedy to be an update in my Maui app .proj file.
If you have:

```
<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
```

change it to:

```
<WindowsPackageType>MSIX</WindowsPackageType>
```

And no other changes are necessary.